# How do I get rid of the .meta file errors when I'm trying to open microgames in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I'm trying to open the karting microgame to get started but I have to go into safe mode every time and I get 999+ errors and 18 warnings. This happened every time I tried to open the LEGO microgame too. All of the errors say

'has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.'

Most of the errors start with something to do with visual scripting, such as:

'Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8\Editor\VisualScripting.Core'

or

'Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/'.

This is the message I get at the bottom of the screen:

'Asset Packages/com.unity.visualscripting/ValidationExceptions.json has no meta file, but it's an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.'

I've tried deleting the library as people have suggested on other questions, I've tried opening it with the latest installer and I've also tried deleting and reinstalling unity. None of these methods worked and they had the exact same outcome (999+ errors and 18 warnings). I think the problem has something to do with a missing file or a file in the wrong location but I don't know how to fix it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to make a new empty project then go to this link and import Lego template https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/lego-microgame-179847

Comment: The same thing happens again before I can import the template

Comment: So the problem is not related to the template, something is wrong with your Unity installation, go to this path on your computer "C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages", find the com.unity.visualscripting folder and delete it, then create a new project and go to the package manager and download anew the VisualScripting package. Let me know if this solved your problem to put it as an answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. It seemed download a new visual scripting package automatically.

Comment: I posted the answer kindly mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to the game template, something is wrong with your Unity installation, go to this path on your computer **C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages** find the **com.unity.visualscripting** folder and delete it, then create a new project and go to the package manager and download anew the VisualScripting package.

Comment: for mac users its: `$HOME/Library/Unity/cache/packages`